# create a dynamic link text and link in Html.ActionLink()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, linked-list, ienumerable

I want to create `@Html.ActionLink(model.country, "Details", "Country")' in a dropdownlist as options..because later on, with different role access will see different link...

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CountryList = db.CountryListTable.Select(x => x.countryName).ToList();
        ViewBag.ctr = CountryList;
        return View();
    }
```

View

```
    @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.ctr)
    {
            <span>@item</span>
            <span>
            @* @Html.ActionLink((string)@item, "Details", "Country"); *@ @* this part throw error due to null *@
            </span>
            <br />
    }
```

`@item` does not null...i dont know why it throw null value when encapsulate with `@html.ActionLink`...

fyi, im using .netFramework 4.0, and MVC4...

I'm quite new MVC n .netFramework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be like:
`Html.ActionLink("Details", "Country", new { country = @item })`

Or try like this:

`<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Country", new { country = @item })">@item</a>`

you are getting null, as you are not passing the parameter to your action method.

Comment: Thanks!2nd method really work though!

just for other reffrence, i thought the first one doesnt because the first parameter need to be string...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!2nd method really work though!

just for other reference, i thought the first one doesnt because the first parameter need to be string...
soo it should be : Html.ActionLink((string)item, "Details", "Country", new { country = @item })

However, i tried this method, but still the same error get thrown...this parameter is null...

actually, i did pass the parameter through the viewbag...or is this not soo called "passing parameters", i dont know...but when i change this @Html.actionlink to just @item, it does list of item...

Thank to Arjit Mukherjee...u did save me alot of time...